# How can I hide namespaces from PhpStorm's code completion?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm asking about PhpStorm, but there is probably a generic answer that would apply to any JetBrains' IDE. It's possible that the answer is "That's not possible".

My problem is that when I use autocompletion to pull in, say, a class called `Person`, the code completion helpfully tries to find all available classes called `Person`:

[image: phpstorm code completion]

I've circled the classes that I would like to see on this code-completion list. As you can see, they difficult to find because there are a lot of classes named `Person` in the `Faker` library, which I do not use outside of unit tests.

What I'd like to do, is somehow ignore the Faker library for code completion so that it's easier to autocomplete the classes that I actually use.

Is it possible?

Comment: ATM I can only think of marking folders with those unwanted classes as "Excluded" -- but this will also stop recognizing them as actual classes in files where they are actually used.

Comment: That will work for my purposes. Thanks!